# how to configure XML::Twig with bugzilla?

Tags: perl, bugzilla, xml-twig

I want to import bugs in bugzilla db from xml file and i got error message after run the following command.

```
perl -T C:\bugzilla\bugzilla\importxml.pl -v C:\bugzilla\bugzilla\mybugs\bug.xml

"ERR: can not import these bugs because bug import is disabled here"
```

Now I found that XML::Twig module is only required to import XML bugs usin the importxml.pl script.

I've downloaded XML-Twig-3.39 from CPAN Download Page: http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/

but i don't know how to configure it with bugzilla ?

any help would be appreciated.

Plz share your knowledge, if anyone knows?

Regards,

Comment: The error message doesn't look like it has anything to do with XML::Twig. This is only a guess, but maybe there's some config option you need to change in order to enable the import. Another thing: try installing the XML::Twig module using [ppm](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.10/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html) that comes with ActivePerl. It will do all the work for you and you needn't worry about where to put stuff.

Comment: @simbabque: Thank you. Yes, there was some config options, you are right :) but i did installed XML::Twig anyway. and Thanks to suggest PPM, that is really good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

move-enabled radio button in bugzilla administration needs to turn on.

Administration -> Parameters -> Bug Moving -> move-enabled.

@simbabque: your comment was really helpful, and suggested tool PPM is really great. thanks.